# Julia integrating differential equations: MethodError: no method matching

Tags: julia, differential-equations

I am trying to vector differential equation in Julia. But I get stuck on the following error warning:

> MethodError: no method matching hDerivative(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Nothing, >::Float64)
>   Closest candidates are:
>    hDerivative(::Any, ::Any) at In[8]:3
>    hDerivative(::Any) at In[13]:3

I am basically unsure about the syntax of the function "hDerivative". I tried returning the differential, but also to make to take "timederiv" as an argument of the function hDerivative, analogously to what I have seen in tuturials about differential equations in Julia, altough this look a little strange (I am used to python).

This is an example of the code I used:

```julia
using DifferentialEquations

N=10
J=randn(Float64,N,N)
g=1

function hDerivative(h,timederiv)
    timederiv=zeros(Float64,N)
    for i=1:length(h)
        for j=1:length(h)
            timederiv[i]=timederiv[i]+J[i,j]*tanh(h[j])            
        end
    end  
end

hinit=zeros(Float64,N)
tspan=(0.0,1.0)
prob = ODEProblem(hDerivative,hinit,tspan)
solve(prob)
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Per the documentation the order of arguments in the ODE function is `function f(du,u,p,t)`, the return vector followed by the state vector and possibly paramters and the time. You have a different order and number of arguments. If you think that should work, please reference the example you are working off of.

Comment: So perhaps `prob = ODEProblem((du,u,p,t)->hDerivative(u,du), hinit, tspan)` could work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@LutzL's comment is exactly correct that the problem with this code is that it doesn't define the derivative function as mentioned in the documentation. Instead, the following code which utilizes the `(du,u,p,t)` form works:

```
using DifferentialEquations

N=10
J=randn(Float64,N,N)
g=1

function hDerivative(timederiv,h,p,t)
    for i=1:length(h)
        timederiv[i] = 0
        for j=1:length(h)
            timederiv[i]=timederiv[i]+J[i,j]*tanh(h[j])            
        end
    end  
end

hinit=zeros(Float64,N)
tspan=(0.0,1.0)
prob = ODEProblem(hDerivative,hinit,tspan)
solve(prob)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now the integrator works, in the sense that it gives an output. However the state after the integration is the same as the initial state using the example code (and changing "hinit" to different values). When I explicitely test the medod "hDerivative" it does not yield zero. So there is still going something wrong and I can't find what.

Comment: @WouterDevos I edited it to fix the issue. Essentially, instead of creating a new array for the output, fill the existing one with zeros.